# Vendor SharePoint Solution

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I'm looking to create a SharePoint site for the following:

-I have three lists: software product, help desk tickets (with a lookup column to the software product), and knowledge base documents (with a lookup column to the software product)

I'd like to create a site that when someone clicks on the software product, they go to a page that shows all the help desk tickets and knowledge base documents for that software product.

I can figure out how to manually do this using data view web parts (XLST list view, if you prefer) - e.g. filter the results - but I haven't figured out how to pass the value that the user selects to the rendered page.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can either just link to the page that is created when you create a list view (AllItems.aspx or CustomList.aspx) or you can use the Query String URL Filter web part, which would allow you to pass in a string via the URL that you could then pass to one or more list web parts.